# How do you get a web object using Jquery in SharePoint?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, jira-rest-api

I am trying to get a web object for a URL to let's say 
http:www.example.com

This is not the context site but I need to create a web object as we do for context.

```
var myWeb = context.get_site().get_rootWeb();
```

Above code works for context only but if I want to get the web of another site in another site collection how do I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can set URL to Client Context like this:

```
var yourUrl = '/sites/yourUrl';
var clientContext;
var web;

// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your
// code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

// Create an instance of the current context.
function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(yourUrl);
    web = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(web);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}
function onRequestSucceeded() {
    alert(web.get_url());
}
function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

May be this help you.